# What are some of the use cases of explicitly creating a CATransaction?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-animation, catransaction

Core Animation docs state that: "One of the main reasons to use transactions is that within the confines of an explicit transaction, you can change the duration, timing function, and other parameters." This is something doable with an explicit CAAnimation. So what are some of the reasons why I want to create a CATransaction?